# information extraction about a person from a document

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nltk, spacy

extract information about a particular person from a document which may contain information about many people. Statements like "he works for XYZ COMPANY", should also be considered for that particular person. Also Nick names should be considered.
I have tried using NLTK and Spacy and have managed to extract entities from the document. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hi @Leanda , First of all welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide some more explanation of what you are trying to achieve and your current progress with output ?

Comment: i want to extract all info a particular person from a given document ,i have used name entity recognition concept for this problem , i am able to extract entities like person,location,money,date etc.but i am not able to link those entities to that belong  to that specific person .

Comment: i am open to other approaches as well to fulfill my main requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try using a more complete NER library, maybe standford coreNLP can help you, https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Comment: can you please elaborate how CoreNLP will help me proceed will it directly give me  the relation between the entities eg person (Mark) and entities related to it or some other thing what will it do ???       thank you for your response